# jQuery data gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

I'm trying the new data-function in jQuery but can't make it work.

Here is a little bit of code I use for testing:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li data-test="list">List item</li>
    <li data-test="list">List item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li data-name="sida">oko</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var test = $('li').data('name');
alert(test);
```

The same thing on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w95mY/1/

I expect to get "sida" from the alert. I found out that it works if I delete the first list. Why is that? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider telling jQuery how to find exactly one element.  For example, tell it to look for any `li` element with a `data-name` attribute:

```
var test = $('li[data-name]').data('name');
alert(test);
```

Or you can tell it to look for the last `li`:

```
var test = $('li').last().data('name');
alert(test);
```

Both show an alert with text "sida".

Comment: I like the first one better. Thanks!